# Rest-Assured/JUnit returns HTTP error code 400

Tags: rest, junit

I wrote a simple REST in Spring boot and a test case written in rest assured returns http code 400 while it works fine from curl.

Service:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customerService")
public class CustomerService
{
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomerService.class.getName());

    @RequestMapping(value = "/customers/{id}", 
        produces = { "application/hal+json", "application/json" }, 
        consumes = { "application/json" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> getCustomer(@PathVariable (value="id") String id)
    {
        logger.debug("getCustomer ["+id+"]");

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        ResponseEntity<Customer> response = ResponseEntity.ok(customer);

        customer.id="10";
        customer.name="Foobar";
        customer.category="Elite";

        return response;
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;

import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

@FixMethodOrder (MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class TestCustomer 
{
    @Test
    public void testStatus() throws IOException
    {
        String token = this.loadContentsFromFile("./src/test/resources/user-token.txt");
        String response = 
                given()
                .header("Authorization",token).and().header("Accept","application/json")
                .contentType("application/json")
                .when()
                    .get("http://localhost:8080/customerService/customers/10")
                   .peek() // Use peek() to print the ouput
                    .asString();

        assertNotNull(response);
        System.out.println("body : " +response);
    }   
    public String loadContentsFromFile(String path) throws IOException 
    {
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
    }
}
```

Test Runner:

```
public class TestSuite {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestCustomerService.class);

        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }

        System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
    }
}
```

Test Output:

```
customer.TestCustomer > testStatus STANDARD_OUT
DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager - Get connection for route {}->http://localhost:8080
DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to localhost:8080
DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: ignoreCookies
DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - Attempt 1 to execute request
DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Sending request: GET /customerService/customers/10 HTTP/1.1
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "GET /customerService/customers/10 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1c2VyIiwiYXVkaWVuY2UiOiJ3ZWIiLCJjcmVhdGVkIjoxNDc5MTM5ODg4NzM0LCJleHAiOjE0Nzk3NDQ2ODh9.YaaNqBXGo3M3fDI0HOL9eRH1G_w0iEZ4ZRxDPE004_QP59ieP20IJv3b1Y74R642yK9I2gjm-YoVvfmM3oqIEQ[\n]"
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Host: localhost:8080[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_112)[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> GET /customerService/customers/10 HTTP/1.1
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1c2VyIiwiYXVkaWVuY2UiOiJ3ZWIiLCJjcmVhdGVkIjoxNDc5MTM5ODg4NzM0LCJleHAiOjE0Nzk3NDQ2ODh9.YaaNqBXGo3M3fDI0HOL9eRH1G_w0iEZ4ZRxDPE004_QP59ieP20IJv3b1Y74R642yK9I2gjm-YoVvfmM3oqIEQ

DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Accept: application/json
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Content-Length: 0
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Host: localhost:8080
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Connection: Keep-Alive
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_112)
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "HTTP/1.1 400 [\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Date: Tue, 15 Nov 2016 02:26:21 GMT[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Connection: close[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 400
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << HTTP/1.1 400 
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Date: Tue, 15 Nov 2016 02:26:21 GMT
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Connection: close
WARN com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder - Could not parse content-type: Response does not have a content-type header
DEBUG com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder - Parsing response as: application/octet-stream
DEBUG com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder - Parsed data to instance of: class org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "0[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager - Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl@32f271d9
DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Connection 0.0.0.0:41492<->127.0.0.1:8080 shut down
HTTP/1.1 400 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 15 Nov 2016 02:26:21 GMT
Connection: close
Executing test testStatus [customer.TestCustomer] with result: SUCCESS
```

Following line says its returning 400:

**DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 400**

Here's the curl request which works fine:

```
curl -v --header 'Content-type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1ZGllbmNlIjoid2ViIiwiY3JlYXRlZCI6MTQ3ODg4ODk0ODExNiwiZXhwIjoxNDc5NDkzNzQ4fQ.nA-5UY3L6HQP-TUjhYgMg1wcQa1Q1GQwPtGxbU3wgctO_c7vMmOd_hhG4Dj28x8dswivVBTCAXYJd1-37CQFfg' \
--request GET http://localhost:8080/customerService/customers/10 \
```

Here's the curl response with returns code 200 and the body:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /customerService/customers/10 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
> Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1ZGllbmNlIjoid2ViIiwiY3JlYXRlZCI6MTQ3ODg4ODk0ODExNiwiZXhwIjoxNDc5NDkzNzQ4fQ.nA-5UY3L6HQP-TUjhYgMg1wcQa1Q1GQwPtGxbU3wgctO_c7vMmOd_hhG4Dj28x8dswivVBTCAXYJd1-37CQFfg
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Tue, 15 Nov 2016 02:47:53 GMT
< 
{
  "id" : "10",
  "name" : "Foobar",
  "category" : "Elite"
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
}
```

So I am trying to figure out what am I doing wrong. One thing puzzles me why rest-assured is adding 'Content-length:0' header to the request. I am learning rest-assured and JUnit testing framework and I am stuck trying to get one GET request to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Found the solution after trying few things out. Apparently, Files.readAllBytes() was adding a linebreak to token value. So I replaced loadContentsFromFile method to use Scanner to read the file which worked well.

```
public String loadContentsFromFile(String path) throws IOException 
{
    Scanner scanner=null;
    String text="";
    try
    {
        scanner= new Scanner(new File(path));
        text = scanner.next();
    }
    finally
    {
        scanner.close();
    }
    return text;
    //      return new String (Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)),Charset.defaultCharset());
    //has a bug it adds a line break at the end.
}
```

So this caused header  `"Authorization: <token>"`  went to server without line break and that worked the rest get call.

I am not exactly sure why Files.readAllBytes() was adding a line break though as I don't have a line break in the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using URIBuilder or something like that make sure you move all the characters it adds for example %3 and so